# where to put logic for cleaning up data from an external system

Tags: oop, domain-driven-design

**Description of the system:**
The system basically processes messages from an external system.

**The way i have modeled the system is :**
1. I created an anti corruption layer that receives the messages (swift messages) from an external system. The ACL also has a reponsibility for cleaning up the data, then lastly, the ACL sends the messages to the domain services for processing.
2. I have the actual domain, that processes these messages, does some calculations etc.

I am having problems with figuring out where to put the logic for 'cleaning' the data that is in the swift messages.

**Swift Message:**
Each swift message is just a BLOB of text containing a various fields and their respective Values

```
{
    :field1://value 1 ***
    :field2://value2!!
    :unwantedField3://value3
}
```

So likewise i have an entity called Message, which contains a list of fields. The problem i am facing is transforming the BLOB of text into a Message entity. This is because each field needs to be extracted differently from the next. So in the example above,

1. the value of field1 must be value 1, without the ***,
2. the value of field2 must be value 2, without the !!
3. field 3 must be ignored

In total, there are 4 different fieldTypes. ***So my question is, where do i put the logic to clean up the fields***,

1. do i put it in an external 'service' that has an if statement to clean each field differently? (anaemic model)
2. Do i put the logic for cleaning in the Field Value-object itself, so each field knows how to clean itself (problem with this is that a Field object resides in the domain and i dont think i should keep logic to clean data in the domain, the domain only deals with clean data)
3. do i create special classes in the ACL that do the cleaning (extracting fields from a BLOB of text)

And does all this logic sit in the ACL or it moves to the domain. I get a sense that the logic for cleaning external data must not sit in the domain, because it has no business sitting there.

```
public class Message: Entity<long>
{
    public IList<Field> Fields{get; set;}
}

public class Field: ValueObject
{
    string Tag {get; set;} // this is what it looks for in the swift message BLOB of text from the external system
    string Value {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the ACL is to fully adapt the data to the domain. It should translate/cleanup the data so the domain does not need to know the details of the other system. As such, the ACL is the correct place for the clean up. However, if the fields are very complex then it is fine to have multiple adapter classes in the ACL to handle the field specific logic. Just ensure the data is fully translated before passing to your domain.

Comment: would you be kind enough to point me in the right direction regarding these 'adapter' classes. What i have so far is, in the domain, i have 4 different field types, all inheriting from Field, the reason i had these 4 different field types was so that i could apply the different cleaning/translation. the cleaning is not complex,it is exactly as i mentioned above,all i need to do,is remove the * in the 1st field,and remove the ! in the 2nd field. the 3rd field has a few chars that i need to remove at the start and end of the value,eg a value can be -value4°°,all i need to remove the - and the °°

Comment: I would not store any tag information in your domain objects; that's breaking the ACL and allowing the details of the swift message to bleed into your domain. Unless your domain is the construction and management of swift messages. If not, then your ACL must translate the data into your domain specific context. In this case, the parsing logic is fairly simple, so I would likely use a single builder method in my ACL that takes a Swift blob and produces my domain object(s).